# Android gradient doesn't achieve what I want

Tags: android

I would like to have a gradient like the one shown below

[image: denko gradient]

I use the following code to achieve what I want:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:startColor="#FFf26922"
        android:endColor="#FFffffff"
        android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

But what I get is the following one.

[image: denko gradient wrong]

What can I do that get what I have intended?

Comment: try to use center colour attribute: android:centerColor="#FFf26922"

Comment: Because you're giving wrong colors.

Comment: `startColor` should be "ff4401"

Answer (score 0):

Correct it

You are giving wrong pattern foa a gradient ...

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient

            android:startColor="#FF4401"
            android:centerColor="#FE632B"
            android:endColor="#FFffffff"
            android:angle="90"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: Fixed mispelled cent**er**Color.

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFffffff"
        android:endColor="#FFFF4401"
        android:centerColor="#FFFE6730"
        android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FFf26922"
        android:endColor="#FFffffff"
        android:startColor="#ff4401"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
 <gradient 
  android:type="linear"
  android:centerX="1%" 
  android:startColor="#FFFA2C09" 
  android:centerColor="#FFFA2C09" 
  android:endColor="#FFffffff" 
  android:angle="90"/>
 </shape>
```